# How to align the content when in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to align the content of an expression when in math mode. **Note:** I've seen a lot of questions that may look similar to this but what I'm asking is not the alignement inside an `equation` block. In other words, I want my equation to be inserted in line: to this scope I use $$ to delimit my equation in the text **but** when the expression inside $$ is too long it goes further the vertical alignement and a new line is inserted only when it terminates.

EDIT:
From my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
[...]then, adding a version counter would turn such policy into "$ECU\_MODEL\_2247\_v\_0 \; \textbf{OR} \; \textbf{(} CAR\_MODEL\_21\_v\_0 \; \textbf{AND} \; ECU\_MODEL\_2248\_v\_0 \textbf{)}$". If a key now gets compromised, then the manufacturer updates the version of the access policy, that now becomes "$ECU\_MODEL\_2247\_v\_1 \; \textbf{OR} \; \textbf{(} CAR\_MODEL\_21\_v\_1 \; \textbf{AND} \; ECU\_MODEL\_2248\_v\_1 \textbf{)}$"[...]
\end{document}
```

The text inside $$ goes beyond the alignement but I don't want to put it in an *equation block* because I would like it to be "inline" as in the document I reported.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to provide a specific example of material you wish to format in a certain way. Please also clarify what, specifically, you wish to achieve.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the suggestions! I edited my question. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that you load the `xurl` package and use its `\path` macro to typeset the long name labels. That way, line breaks inside the long labels are allowed to occur wherever they're needed. (The `\path` macro is a close relative of the `\url` macro; the only real difference is that `hyperref` won't attempt to make the argument of `\path` into a clickable URL string.)

In addition, I would also like to suggest that you not **bold-face** the AND and OR terms; instead, consider typesetting them in small-caps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for robust-looking _ (underscore) characters
\usepackage{xurl}
\newcommand\logic[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
[\dots] then, adding a version counter would turn such policy into 
``\path{ECU_MODEL_2247_v_0} \logic{OR} (\path{CAR_MODEL_21_v_0} 
\logic{AND}  \path{ECU_MODEL_2248_v_0})''. 
If a key now gets compromised, then the manufacturer updates the 
version of the access policy, which now becomes 
``\path{ECU_MODEL_2247_v_1} \logic{OR} (\path{CAR_MODEL_21_v_1} 
\logic{AND} \path{ECU_MODEL_2248_v_1})'' [\dots]
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum: Of course, typesetting the long-ish expressions in a display format would very likely make them easier to read, whether or not a line break occurs.

[image]

To my untrained eye at least, displaying the expressions on lines by themselves makes it much easier to go back and forth and figure out what the pre- and post-conditions are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for robust-looking _ (underscore) characters
\usepackage{xurl}
\newcommand\logic[1]{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
[\dots] then, adding a version counter would turn such policy into 
\begin{center}
\path{ECU_MODEL_2247_v_0} \logic{OR} (\path{CAR_MODEL_21_v_0} 
\logic{AND}  \path{ECU_MODEL_2248_v_0})\,. 
\end{center}
If a key now gets compromised, then the manufacturer updates 
the version of the access policy, which now becomes 
\begin{center}
\path{ECU_MODEL_2247_v_1} \logic{OR} (\path{CAR_MODEL_21_v_1} 
\logic{AND} \path{ECU_MODEL_2248_v_1})\,.
\end{center}
[\dots]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not require math mode, because it does not contain math material. However, in case the expression contains real math material and you need to force a newline inside `$...$`, you can use `\allowbreak`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
[...]then, adding a version counter would turn such policy into
"$ECU\_MODEL\allowbreak
\_2247\_v\_0 \; \textbf{OR} \; \textbf{(}
CAR\_MODEL\_21\_v\_0 \; \textbf{AND} \; ECU\_MODEL\_2248\_v\_0 \textbf{)}$". 
If a key now gets compromised, then the manufacturer updates the version of 
the access policy, that now becomes "$ECU\_MODEL\_2247\_v\_1 \; \textbf{OR} \;
\textbf{(} CAR\_MODEL\allowbreak
\_21\_v\_1 \; \textbf{AND} \;
ECU\_MODEL\_2248\_v\_1 \textbf{)}$"[...]
\end{document}
```

[image]